# onReceive() of Alarm BroadcastReceiver called during setAlarm method is called

Tags: android

Newbie here, I have this function `setAlarm`:

```
 public void setAlarm(){


        SharedPreferences sa=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());


        int hr=sa.getInt("alarmhour", 6);
        int mn=sa.getInt("alarmminute", 0);
        String st1=sa.getString("alarmstatus", "Alarm Disabled");

        if(st1.equals("Alarm Enabled"))
        {

        AlarmManager ala = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent inte = new Intent(this, epicalarm.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, inte, 0);


        Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
        time.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hr);
        time.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mn);
        time.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        ala.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
        }




 }
```

Each time I call the function `setAlarm` , the `onReceive` method gets called and displays the alarm . Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter in

```
ala.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
```

is to specify when to trigger the alarm first. In your code, you are triggering it for the time you read from your shared preferences. If that time has already elapsed, the alarm gets triggered immediately. That may be one reason why the onReceive() method gets called.

Check if the time you read is some time in the future.

Comment: yes thats true, it happens only if the time has already elapsed , cant i stop that?

Comment: Nope, i dont think so. Why would you want to set an alarm for a time that has already elapsed?

Comment: Suppose current time is 11:00 and user wants to set for 10:00 , i would want the alarm to get triggered the next day , not immediately ...

Comment: You have to add a checking condition, whether the alarm is already in past or not. If it's in the past, add 1 day to the calendar. `time.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);`

Comment: Okay, you may use Calendar.before("current time") to check if the time you read is before the current time. And then set your alarm after adding a day to the time you read from the Shared preferences.

Answer (score 1):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();   
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());       
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, h);        
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, m);        
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);        
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);
// if values of h and m are less than current time
//then 'if' block will executes and adds the amount of days as 1 to your calendar object.
if (calendar.before(Calendar.getInstance()))
{
     calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}

//you will get an alarm` after a day instead of now

ala.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
```